# Pointing many domains to same IP/Primary Domain over https(ssl)

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, cdn

Is it possible to add CNAME records/A records  to point many domains to primary domain or IP Address, and keep them over https (ssl)?

Does a multi-domain SSL Cert allow this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

yes. As long as entered server name matches presented SSL certificate name -- SSL connection will authenticate server normally.